# SQL View optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, optimization

I have inherited an existing system and am trying to figure out a few things.

The system does a

```
SELECT * FROM v_myView WHERE mvViewCol = 'someValue'
```

and `v_myView` performs summation of `Table1` based on `myViewCol`

Does SQL Server 2005 optimize the query or will summation always occur across the entire `Table1`?

I understand that I could use a parameterized view but don't want to go changing things unnecessarily.

Cheers
Geoff

Comment: You can try to build query execution plan and see what is happening.

Comment: There is no such thing as a parameterized view in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Aaron. I should have said 'inline table-valued function'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views have no runtime cost at all. They are always inlined into the surrounding query as if you had pasted the view definition as text. They would be impractical to use otherwise.

> Does SQL Server (2005) optimize the query or will summation always occur across the entire Table1.

It will be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question.  I think the best explanation is [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130855&seqNum=6).  I do wish Microsoft documentation were a little clearer on this point.

When a view is created, the query is parsed.  This ensures that it is correct.

The execution plan is determined the first time the query is run (to a close approximation).  This execution plan then remains in the plan cache for subsequent calls.  So, if you have an index on the appropriate columns and the first execution has a `where` clause that would use the index, then subsequent calls will also use the index.

I say to a close approximation, because it is really the first time that a view is called *when the plan is not in the plan cache*.  Certain changes to the database will flush the plan, as will restarting the server.

So, if you only access the view with the `where` clause, then subsequent uses of the view will be optimized for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 will optimize the view each time it is referenced in a query : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

"After view expansion, the SQL Server query optimizer compiles a single execution plan for the executing query."

I don't have 2005 installed but it will operate similiar to 2008R2 - To view the Query Optimization Plan, right click in the query window and select "Display Estimated Execution Plan" for more info and to spot any bottlenecks.

In the Query menu option, there is "Analyse Query in Database Tuning Advisor" that may also be of benefit to you.